# ¿Cómo obtener un texto de HTML con C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy usando la librería ScrapySharp y HtmlAgilityPack en C# .NET para hacer WebScraping y conseguir un texto de la siguiente página [web](https://servers.fivem.net/servers/detail/4ar4k5), me gustaría conseguir el número de usuarios que hay conectados en este momento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo este código pero el error que me da es que no existe, `System.InvalidOperationException: 'La secuencia no contiene elementos'`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlWeb oWeb = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = oWeb.Load("https://servers.fivem.net/servers/detail/4ar4k5");
            HtmlNode Body = (HtmlNode)doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".players-count").First();
            string sBody = Body.InnerHtml;
            Console.WriteLine(sBody);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

¿Cómo podría conseguir este texto si es que se puede? ¡Gracias a todos de ante mano!

Comment: Es muy posible que ese dato se genere de forma dinámica con JavaScript. Si es así ... mal asunto, no podrás obtenerlo.

Comment: @Juanjo sí, creo que es así, ¿no hay ninguna manera? ¿Con otra librería por ejemplo?

Comment: La única forma sería interpretar el JavaScript en tu local. Y eso no es ni mucho menos trivial. No se mucho de `C#`, pero no veo realista que alguien haya metido un interprete de JS con capacidad de manejar el DOM en una librería. Ni de `C#` ni de ningún otro lenguaje.

Comment: Seria bueno tener un HTML de ejemplo (de dicha pagina) para probar. Si es dinamico tambien se puede obtener en el "evento" o momento adecuado. Ademas podrias realizar esto mismo por ejemplo con [Puppeter-Sharp](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp), ya que es chrome por detras y manipulas todo el browser.

Comment: Otra forma es interceptar las peticiones de la página al servidor y replicarlas tú ... pero eso excede mucho de una simple respuesta.

Comment: Vale, te confirmo que la página hace peticiones GET (AJAX) a `https://servers-frontend.fivem.net/api/servers/single/4ar4k5`. Tiene pinta de que es una URL generada dinamicamente por el servidor. A partir de aquí, te toca investigar a tí :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu problema se puede resolver usando [httpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

```
public class ResponseSracpping
    {
 
        public class Data
        {
            [JsonProperty("clients")]

            public int Clients { get; set; }
   
        }
        public class ScrappingRoot
        {
            public Data Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

para convertir el json que da el response del sitio, te recomiendo esta [pagina para convertir JSON a c# classes](https://json2csharp.com/)

aqui puedes tener un mejor control usando interfaces

```
Task<(bool result, ScrappingRoot ResponseDatas, string ErrorMessage)> Scrapping();
```

llamas a tu interfaz

```
 public async Task<(bool result, ScrappingRoot ResponseDatas, string ErrorMessage)> Scrapping()
        {
            try
            {
                var datas = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                datas.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
                datas.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("origin", "https://servers.fivem.net");
                datas.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("referer", "https://servers.fivem.net/");
                datas.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36");

                var responseDatas = await datas.GetAsync("https://servers-frontend.fivem.net/api/servers/single/4ar4k5");

                if (responseDatas.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var res = await responseDatas.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
                    var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ScrappingRoot>(res, options);

                    return (true, result, null);

                }
                return (false, null, responseDatas.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return (false, null, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

el problema aqui es que tienes que llamar tu endpoint para que se actualizen los datos , puedes usar un timeout o si quieres hacerlo mas pro, puedes usar signal r

[image: imagen resultado]

aqui puedes ver el resultado de la pagina
[image: response de la pagina]